# How do I fix Firefox Broken Firefox Open with?

Tags: firefox

I continue to have issues with getting Firefox 15 to properly remember what apps to use to open items with. I'd written previously regarding [properly associating .deb files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185139/why-does-firefox-try-to-use-gedit-to-open-deb-files), and the suggested solution sort of works, but at this point Firefox doesn't want to properly "remember" the "other" selection that I've chosen.

See the screenshot below, where I've chosen Azureus; however, Firefox won't allow me to "Do this automatically from now on." If I click OK here, Azureus/Vuze opens, but the next time I click on a .torrent link I will be back to the same issue. I wondered whether my profile is corrupt and created a new one, but am having the same issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Does this happen everytime you download a file or is it only from a particular website? I'm able to download a .torrent file, for example, from Fedora Project website and see the option enabled (see image below).

Based on these Mozilla support articles

1. [Adding, removing and editing download actions](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file#w_adding-download-actions)
2. [Adding download actions](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file#w_adding-download-actions)

> It can happen if the website's server incorrectly specifies the
>   Internet Media type of the file. It also can happen if the server
>   assigns "Content-Disposition: attachment" to the file.

I'm using the latest version of Firefox which is 16.0.2 and Deluge on an Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit machine.

[image]