# How do I set Ubuntu Software Center as default to apt links?

Tags: apt, software-center, firefox

I was about to install Bank-ID but got stuck with this apt-link. If I click on that link the file manager gives me the opportunity to choose a specific program to open the file.

I can't find Ubuntu Software Center by choosing "browse" and I tried to find any setting to set Ubuntu Software Center as default for apt-links.
I don't even know if that's the correct way of installing this software.
If anyone know any other way,  tell me.

I've been trying on my own for a while so perhaps I might have changed any settings.

I was a bit suspicious so I tried to download skype as well to see if it was possible to install any program using Ubuntu Software Center. That didn't work out.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not know Swedish but generally you can search a software from Ubuntu Software Center(USC). Once you type the name it shows all similar things in its software sources. If the software is not available then you have to add the source of the software to your USC. Then you can simply search select and install. http://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them 
Also try, open USC and tick View > New Application in Launcher

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ubuntu, you can set the default file handler for a certain file type under "Preferences > Applications" and searching for deb. [Why does Firefox try to use Gedit to open .deb files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185139/why-does-firefox-try-to-use-gedit-to-open-deb-files) may be of help.