# Firefox Opening Pdfs in Gedit

Tags: firefox, pdf, gedit

I've just done the latest system upgrade to my Ubuntu LT 14.04 and now pdfs don't open with Firefox; instead they open with Gedit to give mangled nonsense.

After searching around ask Ubuntu I found two useful question/answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185139/why-does-firefox-try-to-use-gedit-to-open-deb-files) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/802628/firefox-opens-pdfs-in-gedit) from which I cribbed the following 'almost'-fix.

I did a fix of this using `vi ./.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` and putting a `#` as follows `#application/octet-stream=gedit.desktop`; and I also added an extra line as follows, `application/octet-stream=evince.desktop`; but I still have a problem.

The pdf is downloaded and then opened rather than simply opened (like it used to...).

Does anyone have any suggestion as to how to modify the line?

**Edit**

This phenomenon may be peculiar to certain urls rather than to the current set-up of my Linux Box.  Using this [link](http://downloads.hindawi.com/journals/cri/2012/893246.pdf) gives the problem described; whereas using this [link](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v31/i07/paper) works as it did in the past.  Your thoughts are welcome.

Comment: what's your setting in Firefox Preferences → applications?

Comment: @luckyrumo Portable Document Format (PDF) Preview in Firefox.  (Found by going to Edit/Preferences with Firefox and then scrolling down).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please comment (add `#`) or remove

```
# application/octet-stream=gedit.desktop;
```

in your

```
~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

That's works for me.

Comment: The mimeapps.list could be located on another place. On my Ubuntu 17.10 ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list does not exist but I have several mimeapps.list files on my profil folder. The one I have to correct was  /home/myprofilname/.config/mimeapps.list.